Neural network that learns ODE's 'refuses to learn' initial conditions
I have implemented a simple network that for now i'm just trying to teach the ODE:
$$\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t} = x$$
Using the simple code below:
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Nadam

import numpy as np

#Simple NN
model = Sequential([
    Dense(5, input_dim=1, activation='relu'),
    Dense(5, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1)
])

#Define parameters
n_epochs = 500

#And time over which we train
timestep = 0.05
time = np.arange(0,5,timestep)

opt = Nadam(learning_rate=0.02)

#Custom training loop using PINN loss.
for e in range(n_epochs):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        x = model(time)
        dx = [(x[i+1]-x[i])/timestep for i in range(len(x)-1)]
        loss = sum((x[1:]-dx)**2)
        print(loss)
    grad = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    opt.apply_gradients(zip(grad,model.trainable_variables))

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#plot result solution
plt.plot(time,model(time))

This NN very easily learns the solution $f(x) = 0$, but when I add an 'initial condition loss' for say, $x(0) = 1$:
loss = sum((x[1:]-dx)**2)+(x[0]-1)**2

The loss function (logged for each epoch) seems to plateau at around 1, which is the loss given by my new initial condition loss. This problem is annoying, since I have seen in papers people doing a similar approach for much harder problems and getting results, such as observing travelling wave solutions for PDEs (see here). What am I missing?

Probably not a math question, but a software question.

I agree that this is framed as a "debug by software" question, but there are some nontrivial mathematics that can explain what some of the problem is, as I have expanded upon in my answer. The question of when and how to use smooth vs. nonsmooth activation functions is a genuinely interesting mathematical question (see this for example https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.06093). I suspect that the only actual implementation error is approximating derivatives instead of using exact derivatives provided by automatic differentiation.

You are using ReLU activation functions, which are nonsmooth, to represent the solution of an initial value problem, which is smooth. This can have the effect of the learned solution being highly nonsmooth and therefore pointwise penalties may not be sufficient to ensure that the solution smoothly proceeds from the initial condition. You will likely see better results if you switch to $\tanh$ or some other smooth activation functions. In the neural ODE and PINN literature, you will find that smooth activation functions are used almost exclusively, whereas nonsmooth activation functions are better for problems that are known to be nonsmooth, such as high-dimensional classification where varying the topology of the data is necessary.

thanks for the insight! The convergence seems more well-behaved now, but I still get the plateau. Having gone down the rabbit hole of references I found one source provide a graph where the loss went to 1e-9 after a few thousand iterations which seems unfathomable to me (for learning x' = 2xt). Would you suggest anything else?

Another thing that may help is using exact derivatives of $x(t)$ in your loss computation instead of finite differences, and normalizing this loss in some way so that the initial condition and ODE parts of the loss are approximately the same magnitude.

Normalising and reducing the timestep variable (to get something closer to exact derivatives) really helped! How do I obtain exact derivatives of my NN approximation?

You are working in Keras so it should be callable through some sort of gradient tape method. I'd suggest looking for other PINN implementations in Keras for exact details.
